# Double Coin Toss

Tags: java, random

If we have to toss two coins.
Do we need **two** random variables

```
Random gen1 = new Random();
Random gen2 = new Random();
int firstCoinToss = gen1.nextInt(2);
int secondCoinToss = gen2.nextInt(2);
```

Or I can do this with **one**

```
Random gen1 = new Random();
int firstCoinToss = gen1.nextInt(2);
int secondCoinToss = gen1.nextInt(2);
```

I am confused because we use two coins and toss should be independent.
So if we are using how it could be independent.

If we have to use **one** instance, when there will be need for two instances?

[Edit:] -> the both coin should be tossed 100 times and then we have to check how many tail or head occurred.

Comment: You question is not very clear, can you elaborate about what homework problem you are trying to solve here?

Comment: Use one instance. You should only create separate instances if you need a repeatable sequence using a seed value. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/25200903/1553851

Comment: You can flip two coins once or one coin twice. Either what both results are random.

Comment: `java.util.Random()` is good enough for many purposes,  but not all. With enough observed outputs the initial seed can be recovered, and then all future output can be predicted. So whether it's good enough is dependent on the particulars of what it's used for. If you are simulating fish reproduction in a lake, it's probably fine. If you're generating numbers for a lottery, it's probably not fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using one instance would still let the results be independent. The `Random` object outputs a Stream of random numbers within the range specified, and the numbers produced are not effected by the previous numbers generated.

The [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) say this about creating two instances:

> If two instances of Random are created with the same seed, and the same sequence of method calls is made for each, they will generate and return identical sequences of numbers.

Answer (score -2):

of course one instance is perfectly fine. Moreover, make it constant

```
private final static Random gen = new Random();

int firstCoinToss = gen.nextInt(2);
int secondCoinToss = gen.nextInt(2);
```

Comment: `static final` != constant

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: The term "constant" generally implies deep immutability. The JLS has an even [narrower definition](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4-300). Your example doesn't fit either usage.